# Outlook 2013 crashes after loading

Tags: windows-10, crash, microsoft-outlook-2013

After upgrading to Windows 10, Outlook 2013 will not stay open.

The splash screen appears with "Loading profile...", then the main Outlook window appears as normal. However, after 1-2 seconds, Outlook closes abruptly with no errors.

I've already tried rebooting and checking Windows Update. What's going on here?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I got to the bottom of this with the [Office Configuration Analyzer Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36852), which pointed out that I had outdated video drivers which could cause conflicts.

According to [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2957336):

> - You have at least two video cards installed in your computer and one of them is an NVidia card (different models) and the other is an Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 card.
> - The Disable hardware graphics acceleration option is not selected in the Outlook Options dialog.
>
> There is a conflict between the hardware graphics acceleration feature and this combination of video hardware when the video drivers are not at the latest version.

After updating both the Intel HD and NVidia drivers, Outlook opened without any problems.